# Scalacheck: generate list of numbers with total less than a certain value

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I need to generate a random list of numbers of a given size whose total is less than a given fixed threshold using ScalaCheck. In other words, do something like:

```
val threshold = 3000    
val listGenerator = Gen.listOfN(2000, Gen.choose(1,2000)) suchThat { _.sum < theshold }
```

While the above expresses exactly what I want to achieve, it doesn't work as the suchThat clause ends up discarding the vast majority of generated values.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this? Every constraint you put on a ScalaCheck generator means more potential inputs that aren't being checked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given your maximum is 3k and you want a list of 2000 with the minimum value of 1, I'd expect a list of mostly 1s and 2s. One solution is below (With current numbers will only generate a list of 1s),

```
val threshold = 3000

val max = 2000
val max = threshold / n

val listGenerator = Gen.listOfN(max, Gen.choose(1,max))
```

The math would change a bit if you allow 0s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the threshold is `T`, and the length of the list is `N`, You can generate this list by picking `N + 1` distinct sorted random numbers within `0 until T`, and then compute the differences between adjacent numbers.

For example, let `T = 10` and `N = 3`, generate 4 distinct sorted numbers first:

```
1, 4, 6, 9
```

By computing the differences of adjacent numbers, you get:

```
3, 2, 3
```

whose sum is 8, less than 10.

Following this, you can have the following generator:

```scala
  def gen(T: Int, N: Int): Gen[collection.Seq[Int]] =
    Gen.pick(N + 1, 0 until T).map(_.sortBy(-_)).map { sorted =>
      (sorted.init, sorted.tail).zipped.map(_ - _)
    }
```